# Вывести текст в определенное время и день через JS

Tags: javascript, css

Есть скрипт, который выводит текст в определенный промежуток времени (с 08:00 до 11:00), все работает. Никак не пойму, как сделать, чтобы он показывал текст в этот промежуток времени но только с Пн по Пт (то есть в субботу и воскресенье он ничего не показывает на странице).

Вот сам скрипт:

```
<div id="stylevz"></div>
<script>
var date = new Date()
if(date.getHours() > 7 && date.getHours() < 11) 
{
    document.getElementById("stylevz").innerHTML = "123";  
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
new Date().getDay();
```

Воскресенье - 0 день, суббота - 6 день.

```
const date = new Date()
if(date.getHours() > 7 && date.getHours() < 11 && date.getDay() > 0 && date.getDay < 6) 
{
    document.getElementById("stylevz").innerHTML = "123";  
}
```

Comment: Так я пробовал - не работает. Чтобы проверить прямо сейчас написал `if(date.getHours() > 7 && date.getHours() < 21 && date.getDay() > 5 && date.getDay() < 0)` и ничего не выводится

Comment: @Михаил Какой день вы ожидаете, чтобы он был БОЛЬШЕ пяти, но при этом МЕНЬШЕ нуля?